# ASP.NET files get corrupted when uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, save-as

I have a problem uploading files to the server.

In my web page I have three different file upload web controls from which I pick the files. To save the files on the server I am using the `FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs()` method.

If I upload files around 200 KB or less everything goes right but when I upload something bigger, like 10MB, their length changes and, when I download it, it is no longer usable.

For example, when I upload a 40KB html file, a 200KB pdf file and a 10MB mp3 file the mp3 file gets truncated and it becomes 200KB long. After some debugging I am not sure where it happens because before using the `SaveAs()` method the file size has already changed.

I have already changed the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` value in the `web.config` file.
This is the code in which I upload the file:

```
string htmlFilename = "";
string pdfFilename = "";
string audioFilename = "";
string folder= "";

if (uploadHtml.PostedFile != null && uploadHtml.PostedFile.ContentLength    > 0)
   htmlFilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadHtml.PostedFile.FileName);
if (uploadPDF.PostedFile != null && uploadPDF.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    pdfFilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadPDF.PostedFile.FileName);
if (uploadAudio.PostedFile != null && uploadAudio.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
   audioFilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadAudio.PostedFile.FileName);

if (htmlFilename != "" || pdfFilename != "" || audioFilename != "")
{
   folder= Server.MapPath("Data/" + txtTitoloStudio.Text);
   if (!Directory.Exists(cartella))
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(cartella);
   }
if (htmlFilename != "")
{
   string htmlSaveLocation = cartella + "/" + htmlFilename;
   uploadHtml.PostedFile.SaveAs(htmlSaveLocation);
}
if (pdfFilename != "")
{
   string pdfSaveLocation = cartella + "/" + pdfFilename;
   uploadPDF.PostedFile.SaveAs(pdfSaveLocation);
}
if (audioFilename != "")
{
   string audioSaveLocation = cartella + "/" + audioFilename;
   uploadPDF.PostedFile.SaveAs(audioSaveLocation);
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Does the FileUpload have a max size limit?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like upload doesnt allow larger than 200mb. This might help you to upload larger files: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shashankyerramilli/2014/02/14/upload-files-to-blob-storage-using-azure-power-shell/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I don't know Azure, I wish I could find a way to just store and retrieve data without using complex solutions. It is a school project and I don't have much time to run into new topics.

Comment: try looking into the dropbox api to save and download files. I have used this before and it doesn't take much time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise, I found my mistake. I specified the wrong file uploader from which upload the audio file. So what my code did was pick the pdf file, giving it the audio file's name and extension and store it as an mp3 file. I changed the file uploader's name and now it works. Thank you for your advices!